# I want to calculate Mean of two columns in python

Tags: python, dataframe, math

I had a column in data frame, namely Pclass with class number 1 2 3
pclass
1
2
3
1
I made dummy of the pclass using get_dummies and I get this value
pclass    class_1    class_2    Class_3
1                 1                0                 0
2                 0                1                 0
3                 0                0                 1
1                 1                0                 0

Now I want to calculate Mean of class_1 and class_2 combined.

[image]

Comment: The mean of which quantity? It seems unlikely to me that you really want to compute the mean of the indicator `0` and `1` values themselves; much more likely that you want the mean of (for example) the *fare* for passengers travelling in first class or second class (as opposed to third class). Can you clarify? What does the original question say?

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right you want to calculate the mean of the values of two columns.

You can go like this if you want to use the inbuilt function:

```
df['Pclass_1'].append(df['Pclass_2']).mean()
```

Or get the two columns as list and calculate by yourself :

```
pclass_1 = df['Pclass_1'].tolist()
pclass_2 = df['Pclass_2'].tolist()

sum(pclass_1+pclass_2)/len(pclass_1+pclass_2)
```